# Memo и префиксы DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

```
В memo1 генерируются префиксы сначала строки, и а в memo3 с конца строки;
В memo2 - выводиться результат;



  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
  i: Integer;
  Data: TDateTime;
begin
for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Data:= DateTimePicker1.Date;
    while Data <= DateTimePicker2.Date do
    begin
      Memo2.Lines.Add(Memo1.Lines[i] + FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', Data));
      Data:= IncDay(Data, 1);
    end;
  end;
```

Проблема том что: 
Если **memo1** пустой, а в **memo3** есть текст, то префиксы в конце - **не добавляются.** **(В этом то и проблема!!!)**.

А если в **memo1 и в memo3** есть текст, то префиксы в конце - добавляются.

**Предполагаю, что загвоздка в цикле:** for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do (то есть, сюда, нужно добавить и memo3, если я правильно мыслю?).

**Как:** добавить условие:

```
Если и в **memo1 и в memo3 есть текст** то префикс **в начале и в конце** добавляется.
Если **memo1 есть текст**, а в **memo3 нет текста** то - префикс **в начале** добавляется.
Если в **memo1 нет текста**, а в **memo3 есть текст** то - префикс **в конце** добавляется.
```

Comment: Давно не писал на Delphi, но разве выражение `Memo1.Lines[i]` не упадет с ошибкой если `i` выходит за границы списка?

Comment: Как насчет `for i := 0 to Min(Memo1.Lines.Count, Memo3.Lines.Count) - 1 do`?

Comment: Что такое min ?

Comment: Добавьте `Math` в секцию `uses`.

Comment: @Raider, Так не срабатывает, по всем трем условиям что выше указаны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  Data: TDateTime;
  line: string;
begin
  Data := Now; 
  for i := 0 to Max(Memo1.Lines.Count, Memo3.Lines.Count) - 1 do
  begin
    line := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', Data);
    if i < Memo1.Lines.Count then
      line := Memo1.Lines[i] + line;
    if i < Memo3.Lines.Count then
      line := line + Memo3.Lines[i];
    Memo2.Lines.Add(line);
    Data:= IncDay(Data, 1);
  end;
  ...
```